# Javascript output the highest value on an array with more than two values each

Tags: javascript

I have this code where it outputs the highest value in document.write using an array that i have declared in that line. This works fine and outputs 56 which is the highest.

```
  function topProduct(productProfitArray) {
     if (toString.call(productProfitArray) !== "[object Array]")  
       return false;
  return Math.max.apply(null, productProfitArray);
    }

document.write(topProduct([12,34,56,1]));
```

Now I want to output the value on an declared array also with a string beside the int value, but I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

```
var productProfitArray = [ {“Product A”: -75}, {“Product B”: -70}, {“Product C”:
98}, {“Product D”: 5}, {“Product E”: -88}, {”Product F”: 29}];


 function topProduct(productProfitArray) {
     if (toString.call(productProfitArray) !== "[object Array]")  
       return false;
  return Math.max.apply(null, productProfitArray);
    }

document.write(topProduct(productProfitArray));
```

I tried to add a variable productProfitArray then doing the function and then tried to output the variable using document.write. Any help would  be appreciated.

Comment: change the quotes in your object keys

Answer (score 1):

You should map the array to get the values:

```js
var productProfitArray = [ {"Product A": -75}, {"Product B": -70}, {"Product C": 98}, {"Product D": 5}, {"Product E": -88}, {"Product F": 29}];

function topProduct(productProfitArray) {
  if (toString.call(productProfitArray) !== "[object Array]")  
    return false;
  return Math.max.apply(null, productProfitArray.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]));
}

document.write(topProduct(productProfitArray));
```